# Accessing nested objects VueJS during for loop

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to dynamically create a form (why? It's 200+ fields long and I am not permitted to modify it).  The entire app is in the VueJs environment.

The problem I'm having is that each field requires different things (obviously). I'm trying to add attributes dynamically to each field, which would allow me to render the entire form dynamically, rather than hard coding a 200+ field form.  So in my stupidity I'm taking more time trying to solve this problem than it would take to just hard code the form. Oh well...

Here's a specific (simplified) example of what I want to do...

```
    data() {
         return {
           form: {
             input1: {value: "", classIWantToDynamicallyAdd: "FieldSizeSmallAF"},
             input2: {value: "", classIWantToDynamicallyAdd: "FieldSizeBigAF"},
             //Repeat 200 times
      }
     }
    }
```

Now ultimately I want to get the *value of "classIWantToDynamicallyAdd"* and :class="*put it here*"

The HTML looks like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <div v-for="(field, index)" in form" :key="index">
     <div class="labelAndInput" :class="**I don't know what to do here**">
       <label>index</label> // Successfully outputs: "input1", "input2", etc...
       <input>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Hopefully that's somewhat clear.  I expected `form.index.classIWantToDynamicallyAdd` to work, but it did not, i got the following error:

> TypeError: "_vm.form.index is undefined".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `:class="[field.classIWantToDynamicallyAdd]"` :

```
<div v-for="(field, index)" in form" :key="index">
     <div class="labelAndInput" :class="[field.classIWantToDynamicallyAdd]">
   ....
       <input>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I tried this as well, actually. The class added is: classIWantToDynamicallyAdd, rather than FieldSizeSmallAF or FieldSizeBigAF (also, I'm regretting using such long demo names lol). I'm really at a loss..

Comment: don't regret we are here to help you, what about `:class="[field.classIWantToDynamicallyAdd]"`?

Comment: The whole thing fails to render and console error = TypeError: "field is null".

Comment: it should work according to [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) or try `:class="[form[index].classIWantToDynamicallyAdd]"`

Comment: I think I may have solved it with your help. Your original suggestion of  `:class="[field.classIWantToDynamicallyAdd]"` was correct. My problem was that I had null values in 'form' and it broke the whole thing.  When all 200+ fields are objects it works as expected. Thanks @everyone for the help... What a wasted day lol

Comment: so try `:class="[field!==null?field.classIWantToDynamicallyAdd:'']"`

Answer (score 0):

You could define those class names on data() and just bind it to **:class**

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/pguti19/hL2vamnw/

More help:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/dynamically-add-class-name/

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>
  Forms:
  </h1>
  <div v-for="(field, index) in form" :key="index">
    <span :class="field.class">
      Using {{field.class}} class  
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      form: {
         input1: {value: "", class: "red-theme"},
         input2: {value: "", class: "blue-theme"},
         input3: {value: "", class: "green-theme"}
      },
      theme1: 'blue-theme',
      theme2: 'red-theme',
      theme3: 'green-theme'
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
</script>
```